# Vim: line-wrap based on commas, not word boundary

Tags: vim, word-wrap

Suppose I have the following:

```
myfunction(arg1 = something, arg2 = blah, arg3 = yeah, arg4 = nowayxavi, arg5 = too long)
```

If I press `gql`, it turns into this:

```
myfunction(arg1 = something, arg2 = blah, arg3 = yeah, arg4 = nowayxavi, arg5 =
           too long)
```

That is nice, but I would prefer to have the following:

```
myfunction(arg1 = something, arg2 = blah, arg3 = yeah, arg4 = nowayxavi,
           arg5 = too long)
```

Is there a Vim setting that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using this format

```
myfunction(arg1=something, arg2=blah, arg3=yeah, arg4=nowayxavi, arg5=too long, arg6=too long)
```

after formatting it will be

```
myfunction(arg1=something, arg2=blah, arg3=yeah, arg4=nowayxavi, arg5=too long,
           arg6=too long)
```

From [PEP8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), scroll down a litte and it says

> Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword
>   argument or a default parameter value.

NOTE: there is a difference between `wrap` and `format`, `wrap` means to **display** a long line in two lines while `format` **changes** the long line to two lines in this situation.

Comment: It could also wrap at `arg5=too`, right (assuming `too long` actually is a string with whitespace inside)?!

Comment: Hi, maybe it's a difference between `wrap` and `format`, answer updated.